# How to do feature engineering of real time data?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I have made a good linear regression model with following step:

1. Data Integration
2. Data normalization/scaling(data preprocessing & feature engineering)
3. Model Building(using linear regression with SGD using cross validation)
4. Testing

My question is if we use this model in production environment then how can we do feature engineering of real time data because this model is built with feature normalization and scaling so how real time data can be normalized and scaled to get a good prediction? We don't need explicit feature engineering for cross validation and testing step because this can be done in data preprocessing step before building a model. What about real time data feature engineering?

you can have a look at the sample problem at [sample linear regression in pyspark](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/4895803001654334/1253884865807279/685654085441754/latest.html)

Comment: Do you have experience with streaming data, in either spark or elsewhere? Typically, it's not necessary to run your feature engineering or whatever at every new data point, but rather in windows/batches. Take a look at Spark's Streaming documentation. It should be helpful.

Comment: Consider a case where we have a training dataset of 1 million rows and suppose we encode one datacolumn with StringIndexer(equivalent to label encoder),Now StringIndexer algorithm will encode the column of 1 million entries and there will be a particular integer/float number for each unique entry, further we split and train the model. Now my question is **In streaming a batch of data having 1000 rows is passed and again we have to do StringIndexing but this time it is done not according to training data. If encoding is not done according to training data how can we expect correct prediction?**

Comment: Sounds like a data formatting issue. This question may be better off at SO or DataScience. Training/test should have the same format (just different values). If you're incoming stream is not correctly formatted to look like training/test, then that appears to be an engineering issue, not a statistics one.